# How can I use a button onchange event to run the selected button's onclick function?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, onclick, onchange

When a radio button within an HTML form is selected, I am hoping that it will run the onclick function that I have linked to it. I tried using onclick instead of onchange earlier but it's not working with the radio buttons. Does anyone have any advice/tips I can use to resolve this issue?

```js
function select(id, job, salary, someBool) {
  console.log(id, job, salary, someBool);
}
```

```html
<form class="choice">
  <input type="radio" id="librarian" name="profession" value="lib" onclick="select('#professionSelect', 'Librarian', 4850, true);">
  <label for="librarian">Librarian: $4,850/month</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="mechanic" name="profession" value="mech" onclick="select('#professionSelect', 'Motorcycle Mechanic', 2800, true)">
  <label for="mechanic">Motorcycle Mechanic: $2,800/month</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="actor" name="profession" value="act" onclick="select('#professionSelect', 'Actor', 3100, true)">
  <label for="actor">Actor: $3,100/month</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="teacher" name="profession" value="tea" onclick="select('#professionSelect', 'Teacher', 4500, true)">
  <label for="teacher">Teacher: $4,500/month</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="doctor" name="profession" value="doc" onclick="select('#professionSelect', 'Doctor', 13000, true)">
  <label for="doctor">Doctor: $13,000/month</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="fire" name="profession" value="fi" onclick="select('#professionSelect', 'Firefighter', 3700, true)">
  <label for="fire">Firefighter: $3,700/month</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="engineer" name="profession" value="engi" onclick="select('#professionSelect', 'Computer Engineer', 9400, true)">
  <label for="engineer">Computer Engineer: $9,400/month</label><br>
</form>
```

Would something like this work?

```
    $(".choice").change(function() {
        $(this).onclick();
    });
```

Comment: Hello mate, I just figured out that you are basically passing data to be shown by the function via HTML and for this we have `data-` attribute in HTML.
I have provided my solution for this. Hope this helps.
There are other ways to resolve your query however this works perfectly for you as per your requirement.

Comment: Let me know if you require any other help. Other Idea that initially came to my mind to set all the values in an array and then use forEach in javascript to evaluate which one was clicked on, but there I was requiring two loops. 

Here by using `data-profession` attribute and sending the values from HTML itself,  we are achieving the same by using just one `forEach() ` !!! Hope this helps.

CHEERS !!!

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the great advice!! :)

Comment: Glad we helped :) Stay Blessed Mate. And Enjoy coding !!! God Bless You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`select` seems to be a word you cannot use in your HTML inline event listener. Use any other non reserved keyword it works.

Also, both `onclick` and `onchange` attributes should work here. Here is an example using both of them:

```js
function boo(name,salary){
console.log(name,salary);
}
function body(name,salary){
console.log(name,salary);
}
function select(name,salary){
console.log(name,salary);
}
```

```html
<form class="choice">
<input type="radio" id="librarian" name="profession" value="lib" onchange="body('lib',4850)">
  <label for="librarian">Librarian: $4,850/month</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="mechanic" name="profession" value="mech" onchange="select('mechanic',2800)">
  <label for="mechanic">Motorcycle Mechanic: $2,800/month</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="actor" name="profession" value="act" onchange="boo('actor',3100)">
  <label for="actor">Actor: $3,100/month</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="teacher" name="profession" value="tea" onchange="boo('teacher',4500)">
  <label for="teacher">Teacher: $4,500/month</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="doctor" name="profession" value="doc" onclick="boo('doctor',13000)">
  <label for="doctor">Doctor: $13,000/month</label><br>
</form>
```

In the above example I have used both `select` and `body`, both are not keywords in JS. But will not work in inline event handlers.

You can use them directly in JS though, as below:

```js
let select = function(){
  console.log(event.target.value);
}
let body = function(){
  console.log(event.target.value);
}
document.querySelector('#librarian').onchange = select;
document.querySelector('#librarian2').onchange = body;
```

```html
<input type="radio" id="librarian" name="profession" value="lib"  />
  <label for="librarian">Librarian: $4,850/month</label>
    <input type="radio" id="librarian2" name="profession" value="lib2"  />
  <label for="librarian2">Librarian2: $4,850/month</label>
```

Probably, why the docs recommend against using [inline event handlers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these).

Keep your JS and HTML separate.

Comment: Thank you for all the excellent feedback! I have implemented this and everything works!

Answer (score 1):

I just figured out that you are basically trying to pass data from HTML itself.

So, Best way is to use `data-` attribute property to do so and set your values on that and handle the rest in Javascript instead of writing a click event their itself.

```js
const professions = document.querySelectorAll("input[name='profession']");

function select(id, job, salary, someBool) {
  console.log(id, job, salary, someBool);
}


professions.forEach((profession)=>{  
  profession.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
    const professionData = profession.getAttribute('data-profession');
  const dataArray = professionData.split(",");
  
  select(profession.id,dataArray[1],dataArray[2],dataArray[3]);
  })

});
```

```html
<form class="choice">
  <input type="radio" id="librarian" name="profession" value="lib" data-profession="'#professionSelect', 'Librarian', 4850, true">
  <label for="librarian">Librarian: $4,850/month</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="mechanic" name="profession" value="mech" data-profession="'#professionSelect', 'Motorcycle Mechanic', 2800, true">
  <label for="mechanic">Motorcycle Mechanic: $2,800/month</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="actor" name="profession" value="act" data-profession = "'#professionSelect', 'Actor', 3100, true">
  <label for="actor">Actor: $3,100/month</label><br>
</form>
```

Try this code. And to know more about data- attribute you can use this w3school resource.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_data-.asp

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use the `change` event on each individual radio element by using the name attribute. Here's a basic example of how you could do this:

```js
$('input:radio[name=profession]').change(function(el) {
        select(this.getAttribute("id"), this.getAttribute("salary"));
 });

function select(profession, salary) {
    console.log(profession + ", " + salary)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="choice">
  <input type="radio" id="librarian" name="profession" value="lib" salary="4850">
  <label for="librarian">Librarian: $4,850/month</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="mechanic" name="profession" value="mech" salary="2800">
  <label for="mechanic">Motorcycle Mechanic: $2,800/month</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="actor" name="profession" value="act" salary="3100">
  <label for="actor">Actor: $3,100/month</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="teacher" name="profession" value="tea" salary="4500">
  <label for="teacher">Teacher: $4,500/month</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="doctor" name="profession" value="doc" salary="13000">
  <label for="doctor">Doctor: $13,000/month</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="fire" name="profession" value="fi" salary="3700">
  <label for="fire">Firefighter: $3,700/month</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="engineer" name="profession" value="engi" salary="9400">
  <label for="engineer">Computer Engineer: $9,400/month</label><br>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way I can access the `select()` function through the onclick event?

The select function is pretty much just: 

`function select(id, job, salary, someBool) {
  console.log(id, job, salary, someBool);
}`

Thanks to Seph Reed for adding that into the code for me :)

Comment: Yes. You can simply call the `select` function from within the change callback, and send the parameters as needed.

Answer (score 1):

a way to do that:

```js
const 
  myForm = document.forms['choice']
, data =
  { lib  : { id: '#professionSelect', job: 'Librarian',           salary:  4850, someBool: true }
  , mech : { id: '#professionSelect', job: 'Motorcycle Mechanic', salary:  2800, someBool: true }
  , act  : { id: '#professionSelect', job: 'Actor',               salary:  3100, someBool: true }
  , tea  : { id: '#professionSelect', job: 'Teacher',             salary:   500, someBool: true }
  , doc  : { id: '#professionSelect', job: 'Doctor',              salary: 13000, someBool: true }
  , fi   : { id: '#professionSelect', job: 'Firefighter',         salary:  3700, someBool: true }
  , engi : { id: '#professionSelect', job: 'Computer Engineer',   salary:  9400, someBool: true }
  }
myForm.oninput = e =>
  {
  console.clear()
  console.log( data[myForm.profession.value] )
  }
```

```css
label {
  display : block;
  float   : left;
  clear   : left;
  margin  : .3em 1em;
  }
```

```html
<form name="choice" >
  <label> <input type="radio" name="profession" value="lib"  > Librarian: $4,850/month            </label>
  <label> <input type="radio" name="profession" value="mech" > Motorcycle Mechanic: $2,800/month  </label>
  <label> <input type="radio" name="profession" value="act"  > Actor: $3,100/month                </label>
  <label> <input type="radio" name="profession" value="tea"  > Teacher: $4,500/month              </label>
  <label> <input type="radio" name="profession" value="doc"  > Doctor: $13,000/month              </label>
  <label> <input type="radio" name="profession" value="fi"   > Firefighter: $3,700/month          </label>
  <label> <input type="radio" name="profession" value="engi" > Computer Engineer: $9,400/month    </label>
</form>
```